# How to store in variables letters from foreign languages?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made application that read some words from TXT file and put them into database. The problem is: when I get words from other languages (that have some 'non english' letters) it looks like this:
[image]
It is possible to store these characters in js variable? It's not necessary to show them in console, but they have to be correct in database.

**EDIT:**

It isn't a problem with code editor, loading from file or database. It is a problem with node.js. When I try to show it:

> console.log("ąężźćó");

these characters are shown as "?" too. It is not a problem with cmd, because I tried to save this string to database and result is the same (and I'm 100% sure that this database can store these characters).

Comment: Save and render as UTF8

Comment: I use both notepad++ and sublime, they both accept unicode (and UTF8 is the default) I don't have to do anything.

Comment: In what format (encoding) are the text files? What format does your database accept? And in what format does your node script deal with them? Somewhere there must be a mistake, please provide the necessary details to get an answer.

Comment: Make sure the files are opened using the same encoding in NodeJS as they were saved. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback `fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', callback)` for example.

Comment: to loading file I use "line-by-line" module https://npmjs.org/package/line-by-line (because this file is really big) but I set there encoding to utf-8

Comment: it is not database, code editor or txt file blame. All of them works good with these characters. It must be something with node

Comment: yes, this is probably node.js fault, when i try to show part of this file using console.log, these characters don't be shown.

Comment: as a recomendation: use linux or osx for developing Node.JS apps, in Windows there are a lot of issues and this one of them, just use ”Lucida Console” font and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript should have no issues storing those characters.

I tried it on my mac terminal and it worked fine so I don't think it's node:

```
> console.log("ąężźćó");
ąężźćó
undefined
>
```

But, I see you're using the windows cmd shell.  There might be other issues but at a minimum, you will likely need to set the code page of the windows cmd shell to utf-8

See: [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

From that post:

> ```
> chcp 65001
> Also, you need to use Lucida console fonts
> ```

Comment: but, if js has no issues storing those characters, why it sends to database these "wrong ones" ("?" instead of ę). My database is MySQL, I use phpmyadmin to manage data in it. When I add manually some data, all characters are right, when I use node.js - it doesn't work

Comment: Your question and the answer covered the console display.  To answer why your node code interfacing with the db is having an issue, you will need to ask that as a question and post some code.

Answer (score 0):

latin-2 chars? in utf-8? looks like a bad encoding (one byte is shown, where is the second one?) This mix will not work.

@Ludwik11 which characters encoding do you use in your mysql connection (jeśli spytać wolno)